# How to setup docker to talk to non-dockerized service on same host

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up a docker container (call it `docker-client`) that will access a MySQL server on `mysql-server:3306`. `mysql-server` is the same host that `docker-client` is on.

I thought I could do this using links and the ambassador pattern, so I tried this:

```
mysql-server$ docker run -d --name mysql_ambassador -e MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://mysql-server:3306 svendowideit/ambassador
```

Then I launched my client like this:

```
docker run --link mysql_ambassador:mysql-server -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Unfortunately, trying to run mysql on the client gives an error:

```
docker-client# mysql -h mysql-server
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Is there any way for the client to stay dockerized, the server to stay non-dockerized, and the MySQL server to continue running on the standard port 3306?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use hostname there are several options:

1) use dns with docker ips.  Just run with --dns option.

2) you can use names and alias:
 first run container with name
    `docker run -i -t --name test1 test_docker /bin/bash` 
 than run next container with --link option
    `run -i -t --link=test1:test_hostname test_docker /bin/bash`
after that name will be assosiated with proper ip:

```
`root@1b6a491653e2:/# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.45.232   1b6a491653e2
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.45.230   test_hostname`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IP of the host in the environment variable `MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP` when starting the ambassador container, instead of the hostname `mysql-server`.

However, if you just want to connect to a service on the same host that the docker container is running on, you can do so by using the IP of the host (no need for ambassador), e g

```
docker-client# mysql -h 192.168.100.42
```

Comment: Unfortunately my whole goal is to use the hostname. When I run the dockerized service locally, mysql-server will be on the same host. When I run it in the cloud, mysql-server will point either to the same host or to a separate cloud server.